# Gruntfile config loop to get paths of different and use them

Tags: loops, path, gruntjs, directory

I have a grunt file which takes care of my sass compilation with compass. I am building a couple of libraries, and for now i've got like 15 of them. I used to compile all of my sass into a seperate folder and have everything in one file. For this part I am ok.

My libraries structure is like this:

```
lib/buttons/lib/scss/buttons.scss
lib/buttons/lib/scss/_variable.scss
lib/buttons/lib/js/buttons.js
```

... and so on...

Now I want to loop through each library and compile the scss files in a folder which would be in the library itself like this:

```
lib/buttons/dist/css/buttons.css
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't know of an easy way to do this with just the basic `sass` task options, but you might be able to write a custom task to generate the various targets you would need.

Comment: @jakerella 
Do you have any example of how to do this because I cant see how to do it. Thanks

Comment: I haven't done _exactly_ this, no... but I have a [blog post on custom tasks](http://jordankasper.com/bending-grunt-to-your-will-with-custom-tasks-part-1) you could start with. I'll see if I can work up an example. (But I'm also hoping someone else has an easier solution for you. ;) )

Comment: okay. That would be great. I am checking your blog post. Thanks